# How can I create a 2d array of integers?

Tags: python, numpy, integer, 2d, numpy-ndarray

How do I create a 2D array of zeros that will be stored as integers and not floats in python? `np.zeros((10,10))` creates floats.

Comment: np.zeros((10, 10), dtype = int)  [from](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-zeros-python/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [numpy.full](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.full.html)

> numpy.full(shape, fill_value, dtype=None, order='C')

```
np.full((10, 10), 0, dtype=int)
```

Or [numpy.zeros](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html#numpy.zeros)

> numpy.zeros(shape, dtype=float, order='C')

```
numpy.zeros((10, 10), dtype = int)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use full method

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.full((3,4),10) # will return a 3 X 4 array setting values to 10
```

There is also full_like , the main difference is to use the shape of  an existing array and create another with the same shape but you can put any setting value 
here an example :
import numpy as np

```
x = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3) # so x =np.array([[1,2,3],
                                                [4,5,6])
```

and you want an array with the same shape (2,3) but with 10 values

```
arr = np.full_like(x,10) # arr=np.array([10,10,10],
                                        [10,10,10])
```

Answer (score 0):

A line like this should also work: `[[0 for i in range(10)] for i in range(10)]`

Answer (score 0):

by using "`*`" operator, replicate the list.
`np.reshape([data]*row*column, (row, column))`

in your case data = 0, row & column = 10.

```
np.reshape([0]*100, (10, 10))
```

applying another solution which contain loops, consume more time.